# Save Mysql data in xls using php

Tags: php, mysql, xls

I want to export data in xls format using PHP. But instead of download information, they are displayed in my web page.

```
//connection to database
//building of all information -> ($righe)

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: esporta_utenti.xls");
print $righe;
exit();
```

`$righe` is my tuple

Comment: follow proper header `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="esporta_utenti.xls"');`

Comment: It doesn't work, script behaves in a same way

Comment: You may outputting something before `header()`. comment all code before `header` and you will get it right.

Comment: sorry @JithinJose but I don't understand what are you saying. If I comment all code before header() $righe will be empty

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Pragma: public');   // required
header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header('Content-Type: '.$mime); // file mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));    // provide file size
header('Connection: close');
readfile($file_name);       // push it out
exit();
```

This code was originally Published here http://davidwalsh.name/php-force-download . And can be referred for a detailed explanation of the Code.